# Weird python key error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    ClosestCommonAncestor("A","C",x)
  File "C:\x\x.py", line 149, in ClosestCommonAncestor
    b = tree[otu2][0]
KeyError: ('ADBFGC', 14.5)
```

This is the function that returns the error.

```
def ClosestCommonAncestor32 (otu1,otu2,tree):
    while True:
        a = tree[otu1][0][0]
        while True:
           b = tree[otu2][0]
            if a == b:
                return a
            otu2 = b
        otu1 = a
```

this is the tree input

```
{'A': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'C': [('ADBFGC', 14.5), None, None], 'B': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'E': [('ADBFGCE', 17.0), None, None], 'D': [('AD', 4.0), None, None], 'G': [('BFG', 6.25), None, None], 'F': [('BF', 0.5), None, None], 'ADBFG': [('ADBFGC', 6.25), ('AD', 4.25), ('BFG', 2.0)], 'BF': [('BFG', 5.75), ('B', 0.5), ('F', 0.5)], 'ADBFGC': [('ADBFGCE', 2.5), ('ADBFG', 6.25), ('C', 14.5)], 'ADBFGCE': [None, ('ADBFGC', 2.5), ('E', 17.0)], 'BFG': [('ADBFG', 2.0), ('BF', 5.75), ('G', 6.25)], 'AD': [('ADBFG', 4.25), ('A', 4.0), ('D', 4.0)]}
```

I don't understand this, I thought Keyerror was when it requested a key that didn't exist?
Thanks

Comment: Aren't you missing a `[0]` in the line `b = tree[otu2][0]`? (also, the line `otu1 = a` is unreachable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought Keyerror was when it requested a key that didn't exist?

That's right.

However, there is no key `('ADBFGC', 14.5)` in your dictionary. The tuple is indeed present in one of the value lists, but it's not a key. The dictionary's keys are `'A'`, `'C'`, `'ADBFGC'` etc.

To just use the first element of the tuple to index into the dictionary, write `tree[otu2[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Therefore somehow you are setting `otu2 = ('ADBFGC', 14.5)`, and probably trying to use that to index into a list which expects an integer.